# Sorting doubles in java

Tags: java, sorting, double

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(args[0])));
    String line;

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
        int len = st.countTokens();
        Double[] seq = new Double[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            seq[i] = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
        Arrays.sort(seq);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (i > 0) System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(seq[i]);
        } System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
}
```

So I'm trying to solve this CodeEval problem (https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/91/) and my solution is not getting through all the test cases. I think my method of output is correct (spaces between numbers, trailing newline). I can't figure out what may be going on in the sorting or anywhere else.

The solution is apparently not correct when using floats either.

Comment: What is your output given their input?

Comment: Some of us aren't going to go examine CodeEval - it's up to you to define the problem for us, tell us what you've tried, what happened, and what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also think this is a printing problem. The output seems to require *exactly* 3 decimal places on each number, based on the sample I/O. But, if you print out a double like `70.920` (one of the example inputs) it will display as `70.92`.

```
double d = 70.920;
System.out.println(d);
System.out.printf("%.3f", d);  // <-- try this
```

```
70.92
70.920
```

Notice how the second output is consistent with the format of the sample output whereas the first is not.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized after testing with the sample input that it was not printing as many decimal places as it should. Oops :D It works now, so that was likely the problem. I didn't read the output correctly the first time. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You may be sorting correctly but printing incorrectly. Decimal numbers are represented approximately. The runtime attempts to show them in the short format, but that is not guaranteed.

All the examples they gave should work, but who knows what the test suite does in the background.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the 3 digit doubles you are talking about?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: The link contains `-38.797` which is represented as `-1.0011011001100000010000011000100100110111010010111100 * 2 ^ 5` I can't get any of the tools handy to me to print it as its full form however (all of them realize it is supposed to be the decimal representation, since the difference is quite small). Typically the error would manifest as `-38.7969999` or similar.

Comment: The `Double.toString(double)` will print the same value you parsed up to 16-digits. Just because it has a slightly different representation doesn't meant that toString doesn't correct for this already.  BTW You can use `new BigDecimal(-38.797)` to see what it looks like in decimal. Which is `-38.796999999999997044142219237983226776123046875` but when you print `-38.797` that is what you get.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Didn't know offhand what Java's length guarantees are. (And don't have an environment handy to test that exact language). Updated to focus better on what I really meant the problem was, you were correct that I had focused my wording on a bad example.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `double` not `Double` and I would only sort the values after reading the all, not after every line.

Perhaps some inputs have more than one line?

Comment: Each line's supposed to be sorted separately, I believe. Any reason double is preferred?

Comment: @user82483 It's faster and smaller by as much as 100x.